# Scala, mapping a list to a sparse vector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD of

```
Array[(String, Iterable[(Int, Double)])]
```

with it's elements look like

```
(000267537-01,List((25,0.01), (35,120.0), (26,2.0), (38,130.0), (21,45.0), (54,180.0), (39,10.0)))
```

Now with a constant number 56, I want to convert the List part of the RDD into a sparse vector. So I did:

```
val my_rslt = my_rdd.map(x => (x._1, Vectors.sparse(56, x._2)))
```

then I got an error message:

```
<console>:37: error: overloaded method value sparse with alternatives:
  (size: Int,elements: java.lang.Iterable[(Integer, java.lang.Double)])org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector <and>
  (size: Int,elements: Seq[(Int, scala.Double)])org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
 cannot be applied to (Int, Iterable[(Int, scala.Double)])
       val my_rslt = my_rdd.map(x => (x._1, Vectors.sparse(56, x._2)))
                                                    ^
```

So what was going wrong here? How does the "Vectors.sparse" work?

Comment: maybe this solution help you: `Vectors.sparse(56, my_rdd.flatMap(x=> x._2))` result: `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = (56,[21,25,26,35,38,39,54],[45.0,0.01,2.0,120.0,130.0,10.0,180.0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of times, I figured it out that I should do:

```
val my_rslt = my_rdd.map(x => (x._1, Vectors.sparse(56, x._2.toList)))
```

Although I am still confused about the effect of applying "toList" to a list.

Comment: It's pretty clear from the error message. `sparse` takes an argument that is a `Seq[(Int, Double])`. `Iterable` is further up the [type hierarchy](https://docs.scala-lang.org/resources/images/tour/collections-immutable-diagram.svg) than `Seq`, so an `Iterable` cannot be coerced into a `Seq`. By calling `toList()`, you're changing your `Iterable` to a `List`, which extends `Seq`, so everything is OK. The message is a little confusing due to Spark's Java-specific methods which in this case accept Java `Iterable`s, but just keep in mind that Scala's `Iterable` <> Java's `Iterable`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation!